# How to create a logical expression dynamically(@Runtime) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, runtime, expression

I have the following objects passed to a function say 'evaluateExpr':
`var d = { "Brand" : "Brand 1", "Product" : "P1"} , var key = 'Brand' //or 'Product', var value = 'Brand 1' //or 'P1'`

I need to create an expression in the function that is evaluated at run time as follows

```
var evaluateExpr= function(d,key,value){  
       var expr = d[key] === value;  //should evaluate as d['Brand'] === 'Brand 1', if key = 'Brand' and value = 'Brand 1'
       return expr;
```

I have tried many things. But the `d[key]` always returns the value at  it's index position. For example, it gets evaluated like so,

```
 'Brand 1' === 'Brand 1'
```

Rather it should be evaluated like this,

```
d['Brand'] === 'Brand 1'
```

How do I prevent the Javascript engine from evaluating d[key]  and leave it as it is?

Comment: `var key = 'Brand' or 'Product'` has wrong syntax. There is no `or` operator in JS.

Comment: [""+key] is redundant, just use the key; also, I cannot reproduce this issue. I suspect user error.

Comment: The 'Brand' or 'Product' was meant just as an indicator to indicate possible values for key. I have updated the question to make it a comment.

Comment: I have updated the question to be more comprehensible. What do you mean by user error? Do you want me to post the actual code here?

Comment: I tried this and it's working. I would like to delete this question. How is this possible?